# Trying to read and image using python, error is:'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, image, error-handling, encoding, utf-8

Trying to grab an image from an https link and read it as binary but failed.

```
import requests
file=requests.get("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dPARXQO8dkw/hqdefault.jpg").content
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        contents = f.read()
```

codec is faling to decode giving following error:

```
utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: `.content` is already the binary content of the requests response, you don't need to perform an `open` on it since you're not actually opening a file that's on your system.

Comment: how silly! was stuck at this for 1/2 hr